# getting story tags from graph api returns strange id results for the tagged

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, json

The best way for me to explain this is to show you.  Seems like a float() error in a 64bit system.

when i call `/anotherfeed/feed` or any page for that matter,  posts with story_tags return some of the id's as a float error.

sample story tag with float error in id.  `[id] => 1.7153566624E+14`

My question is, how do i fix this, or what am i doing wrong?  all i am doing is looping in a foreach statement.

```
        if($fvalue[story_tags]){
                echo 'Tags: ';
                $sTags=$fvalue[story_tags];
            foreach ($sTags as $skey=>$svalue){
            foreach ($svalue as $gkey=>$hvalue){
                $id=$hvalue[id];
                echo ''.$hvalue[name].' '.$id.' ';
                            }
            }
        }
```

---

```
               [story_tags] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 1.7153566624E+14
                                        [name] => Another Feed
                                        [offset] => 0
                                        [length] => 12
                                        [type] => page
                                    )

                            )
```

---

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 171535666239724_156133294510726
                    [from] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Another Feed
                            [category] => App page
                            [id] => 171535666239724
                        )

                    [story] => Another Feed shared Non-Profits on Facebook's photo.
                    [story_tags] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 1.7153566624E+14
                                            [name] => Another Feed
                                            [offset] => 0
                                            [length] => 12
                                            [type] => page
                                        )

                                )

                            [20] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 41130665917
                                            [name] => Non-Profits on Facebook
                                            [offset] => 20
                                            [length] => 23
                                            [type] => page
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [picture] => http://photos-d.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/557037_10150932300320918_1908237167_s.jpg
                    [link] => http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10150932300320918&set=a.85612830917.95996.41130665917&type=1
                    [name] => Wall Photos
                    [caption] => Have you heard of the @[159208207468539:274:One Day without Shoes] (ODWS) campaign?  ODWS is an annual initiative by @[8416861761:274:TOMS] to bring awareness around the impact a pair of shoes can have on a child's life.  

During the 2012 campaign, @[20531316728:274:Facebook] drove 20% of traffic to the ODWS microsite and TOMS even launched a Facebook-exclusive "Barefoot & Blue" giveaway with @[25266987484:274:Essie Nail Polish] for the second year in a row.  

We think this is a pretty cool example of creating exclusive content around an important initiative that keeps people engaged and involved!
                    [properties] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => By
                                    [text] => Non-Profits on Facebook
                                    [href] => http://www.facebook.com/nonprofits
                                )

                        )

                    [icon] => http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yD/r/aS8ecmYRys0.gif
                    [type] => photo
                    [object_id] => 10150932300320918
                    [application] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Photos
                            [id] => 2305272732
                        )

                    [created_time] => 2012-07-02T17:57:23+0000
                    [updated_time] => 2012-07-02T17:57:23+0000
                    [comments] => Array
                        (
                            [count] => 0
                        )

                )
```

Comment: How are you making the API call? Do you do the HTTP request by yourself, and then use json_decode on it? If so, set the option JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING on json_decode.

Comment: so far just php sdk, in foreach, i also did cURL to graph api using 
$locs=json_decode($returned, true);
print_r(json_decode($returned, true));

my curl example is here  http://anotherfeed.com/curl.api.php?pageid=anotherfeed&type=feed

you can input any page username in the pageid to test,  eg: pageid=facebook  pageid=platform pageid=yourpage.  

i will test bigint  - my solution i was hoping for php sdk though.

Comment: i had no luck with bigint, if you look at the example the id in the array is still returning the same.

// $returned = the encoded array.
print_r(json_decode($returned, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**solution:**

*cURL* - had to use number format with PHP_EOL to solve in cURL.

// $locs = curl call to graph api for /anotherfeed/feed, still need solution for foreach.

```
$locs=json_decode($returned, true);
$stId=number_format($locs[data][1][story_tags][0][0][id], 0, '', '').PHP_EOL;
echo $stId;
```

---

*PHP-SDK*

solution is same, long numbers in the foreach loop need to be ran through number_format.